# Having a case statement in where clause along with constant value in Oracle causes wrong results

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am executing the same queries in Oracle and SQL Server but the results are different. Ideally, I am expecting the SQL Server results as my desired output.
Please let me know how Oracle treats the query and gets the below results.
If i change the where condition in Oracle to '*where b.a between 1 and (select case when 4>2 then 4 else 2 end from dual)* ' then i get correct results.

I am using **SQL Server 2008** and **Oracle 11g**

**Full Oracle version:** 
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
CORE    11.1.0.6.0  Production

[image: SQL Server query and result]

[image: Oracle Query and result]

**Code : Oracle**

```
select *
from (
  select 1 a from dual union
  select 2 from dual union 
  select 3 from dual union 
  select 4 from dual union 
  select 5 from dual
)b
where b.a between 1 and (case when 4>2 then 4 else 2 end)
```

**Code : SQL Server**

```
select *
from (
  select 1 a union
  select 2 union 
  select 3 union 
  select 4 union 
  select 5) b
where b.a between 1 and (case when 4>2 then 4 else 2 end)
```

Comment: [Please post text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). But I get the same 4 results back from 11.2.0.4, so which version/patch level of Oracle are you using? (And why have you referred to 11g in the question text but tagged it as 10g?)

Comment: I get 1,2,3,4 in Oracle 12.1.0.2, 12.2.0.1 and 11.2.0.3

Comment: Are you aware that 11.1.x is no longer supported by Oracle?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have added text and changed the tag to 11g

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for trying.

Comment: I get 1,2,3,4 in Oracle Enterprise 11.2.0.4. So this seems to be a bug that has been fixed with 11.2.

Answer (score 0):

Under what circumstances is 4>2 supposed to be false? 
Why not write between 1 and 4.

```
select *
from (
  select 1 a from dual union
  select 2 from dual union 
  select 3 from dual union 
  select 4 from dual union 
  select 5 from dual
)b
where b.a between 1 and 4
```

Comment: That wasn't the question though, was it? I see no connection between this so-called "answer" and the question that was asked. Not helpful!

Comment: To answer your question though: It is very unlikely the OP has code that looks exactly like that. (From the entire question and interaction with others, it is pretty clear he's not a beginner.) Rather - as all posters should, but don't - it is much more likely that the OP ran into a bug, then simplified it as much as possible while still being able to reproduce the bug. EXACTLY what one should do when they troubleshoot.